# Can I find a list of objects that do not support the Kanban view?

Tags: financial-services-cloud, kanban

I recently discovered while working with Financial Services Cloud
that several FSC objects, including FinancialDeal, do not support the Kanban view.

However, it's hard to distinguish whether they truly do not support it officially, or if this is due to some error.

I wonder if there are any kind of lists or something Salesforce officially mentioned.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable a Path for Financial Deals.  Go to settings, type 'Path' in the quick search.  You should see Financial Deals in the list, click edit and walk through the steps.  yourdomain.com/lightning/setup/PathAssistantSetupHome/home

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.path_enable.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was about the kanban view used in listview. I'm already using the path.